# Length of List with conditionals in dart

Tags: list, dart

Is there a way to get 4 instead of 2 as a result?

```
List<String> test = [
      'first',
      'second',
      if (false) 'third',
      if (false) 'fourth',
    ];

    print('length: ' + test.length.toString());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The length property on lists returns the number of elements in the list. In you example you are only inserting two values (because of the condition) so a length of 4 would not make sense and would give problems when you e.g. want to iterate over the list.

You can however add null elements if the condition are false like this:

```
void main() {
  List<String> list = [
    'first',
    'second',
    (false) ? 'third' : null,
    (false) ? 'fourth' : null,
  ];

  final listLengthIncludingConditions = list.length;

  list.removeWhere((x) => x != null);

  print('Number of possible elements in list: $listLengthIncludingConditions'); // 4
  print('Number of elements in list: ${list.length}'); // 2
}
```

You can then save the length and remove the null elements.

Comment: I can't use null as an element of my list as it will crash my UI. I don't want to get 4 by getting the length but maybe there's another way.

Comment: Updated answer so the list don't contain null elements after it has been counted.

Comment: Thought about that one too. It's a hacky workaround tho.